# Whenever I evolve a Pokemon, other Pokemon of the same evolution line's candy disappears?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'll explain. I have a Graveler with approximately 20 candy. When I evolve a Geodude into a Graveler, the Graveler I already have now has 1 candy and the new Graveler also has 1 candy. So I can never get higher on a Graveler to evolve because every time I evolve a Geodude, the Graveler loses all its candy.

This also happens to me with the Nidorino/Nidorina.

Any ideas?

Comment: Each Pokemon do not have their own pool of candy. The number of candies is accumulated between the Pokemon in that evolution tree.

Comment: @Wondercricket if you have solid proof of this you may want to post this as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Candies are shared, if you want to get a Golem you need to stop evolving Geodudes until you have enough candies.

Candies aren't specific to an individual pokémon - they are shared across an evolutionary line. This means that you have a pool of Geodude candies that any of your Geodudes, Gravelers or Golems can dip into and use.

If you have 25 Geodude candies then you have enough to evolve a Geodude into a Graveler. This will consume all 25 of those candies from your shared pool, then give you 1 back as a reward for evolving the pokémon. But this also means that you'll now be 99 Geodude candies short of evolving Graveler into Golem instead of the 75 short that you were previously.

Remember: the pokémon in each evolutionary line *all use the same candy for everything*. Geodudes uses 25 **Geodude** candies to evolve into Graveler and Graveler uses 100 **Geodude** candies to evolve into Golem. If you're spending stardust to power them up, all three will use one or more Geodude candies in conjunction with the stardust to increase the pokémon's CP.

Comment: So I would just have to catch Gravelers if I want to evolve to a Golem. That sucks. lol. Thank you very very much for the answer.

Comment: @Tracy: That's not how candies work at all. You have a pile of geodude candy. You can use that candy to 1) power up geodudes, gravelers, or golems, or 2) evolve geodudes or gravelers. Anything you do with with a geodude, graveler, or golem will use up some geodude candy from your pile. Candy is not for specific individual pokemon in any way.

Comment: @Tracy Does my edit or Ellesedil's comment help make it clearer?

Comment: I get it now, thank you. I thought I had to keep doing the smaller ones and now I can see if it goes to the higher levels and evolve them! I feel so stupid, lol. thanks for all your help!